# Area and Centroid of a Polygon

Tags: c

i got a programm in the school, and i have to tell everyone what is it doing. The programm i got is a program that calculates the area and the centroid of  polygon. Now, i know almost everything, but there are in the program two numbers, i can do nothing. -10001 and -47. If i replace them, the program does not make the calculating right. Can you tell me why -10001 and 47? If i add instead of -10001 and -47 the caculating is right..

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>

typedef struct
{
    double x,y;
} POINT;

POINT c, o, p[10000];

double a, q=0.0;

int n;

double ccw(POINT a, POINT b, POINT c)
{
    return a.x*b.y + a.y*c.x + b.x*c.y - c.x*b.y - b.x*a.y - c.y*a.x;
}

int main(void)
{

    int i, j;

    o.x=-10001;
    o.y=-47;
    **/* THIS IS WHAT*/**
    while (scanf("%d", &n) > 0)
    {
        if(!n)
            break;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            scanf("%lf %lf", &p[i].x, &p[i].y);
        a=0;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
            a += ccw(o, p[i], p[(i+1)%n]);

        c.x = c.y = 0.0;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            q = ccw(o, p[i], p[(i+1)%n])/(3.0*a);
            c.x += q*(o.x + p[i].x + p[(i+1)%n].x);
            c.y += q*(o.y + p[i].y + p[(i+1)%n].y);
        }

        printf("%.3lf\n", fabs(a) / 2.0);
        printf("%.3lf %.3lf\n", c.x, c.y);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it C, or is it C++? It can't be both.

Comment: @PreferenceBean It is C.

Comment: Then why did you use the C++ tag!

Comment: @PreferenceBean It was just a little accident, sorry

Answer (score 1):

The point `o` is just an arbitrary reference point. You add triangles made up of each edge of the polygon and that point. Because the area has a sign, clockwisde and anticlockwise triangles will eliminate each other. The point may lie anywhere; it may even be one of the polygon's vertices.

The figure below shows how the triangles have a different weight: the triangle `23o` is clockwise and has a positive contribution to the area; the triangle `05o` is anticlockwise and has a negative contribution. It is easy to see that the difference of positive and negative triangle areas is the area of the polygon.

[image: calculating the area of a polygon by summing traingle areas]

The area of the triangle is calculated via the cross product of two sides of each triangle, `(b - a)` × `(c - b)`. The absolute value of the resulting vector is the area of the parallelogram created by the two vectors. The cross product of two vectors in the `x`, `y` plane has only a `z` component. Depending on the sense of circumference that component is either positive or negative.

If the reference point is far away from the triangle, floating-point summation may lead to inaccuracies, especially when calculating the centre point of the triangles. (Try it out with a reference point of, say, `{1.0e+12, 1.0e+12}`.)

Therefore, it would be a good idea to make the first vertex the reference point. You can then also leave out the first and last segments, because they are degenerate triangles and don't contribute to the area or center:

```
    a = 0;
    for(i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        a += ccw(p[0], p[i - 1], p[i]);
    }

    c.x = c.y = 0.0;
    for(i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        q = ccw(p[0], p[i - 1], p[i]) / (3.0 * a);

        c.x += q*(p[0].x + p[i - 1].x + p[i].x);
        c.y += q*(p[0].y + p[i - 1].y + p[i].y);
    }
```

This will also get rid of the need to wrap the index.

Comment: And can you help me with its mathemathics? I found on wikipedia a formula.
https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/a/4/c/a4cee81a1d18e4d067f66d4d40a8a1fe.png
it works perfectly for triangles, but for polygons, it doesnt. I have to show the others its mathematics, but the results are different what i get in the programm. If i make it for a triangle the result as i get is the same what the programm gets.

Comment: I've extended the answer. The image shows how the area of the polygon is made up by adding the triangles with the "far" edges and subtracting the "near"  edges. The function `ccw` calculates a cross product, which describes the area of the parallelogram between the vectors; hence the division by 2. The calculated centre of gravity is a weighted average of the centres of the triangles where the weight is the triangles'  area.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Now i understand!